# Inserting Image into textField from customKeyboard

Tags: swift, keyboard

I'm currently making my own customKeyboard Extension, i have Images as buttons which are to be printed into a text Field fx, imessages. So far I've been using
`self.textDocumentProxy.insertText("text")`
which inserts text but what func do i need to call to insert an image. The app joy emoji keyboard does this but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I have used many third-party keyboards, and I believe you can only have the user copy and paste the image into the text field.

Comment: Doesn't it work the same ways GIFS? Were you click the movie and it insert directly into your conversation?

Comment: Same thing. The keyboards would require you to hold down on the image/GIF, it would copy, and then the user would have to paste it in the text field themselves.